# Popover in iOS not displayed near or relative to a button

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to display a popOver next/relative to a UIButton. My current popOver always defaults to the top left corner. Even tried setting sourceRect, sourceView but still it makes no difference. Any idea what else can cause this?

```
lazy var launchButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.setTitle("Launch", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(launchPopOver), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func launchPopOver() {
     let pop = PopViewController() 
     pop.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
     pop.preferredContentSize.height = 250

    if let popPresentation = pop.popoverPresentationController {
       popPresentation.sourceView = launchButton
       popPresentation.sourceRect = launchButton.bounds
    }

    present(pop, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.view.addSubView(launchButton)
}

class PopViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
 //
 public func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
      return .none
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of how it looks with your code, and how you want it to look?

Comment: Unable to share a screenshot at the time... But it looks like an alert box in top left corner.

Comment: I can't reproduce "always defaults to the top left corner", but perhaps `permittedArrowDirections` is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you shouldn't be using `launchButton.bounds` but `launchButton.frame` instead for the `sourceRect` value as bounds will typically resolve to having position of `{ x: 0, y: 0 }` which would explain the

> "always defaults to the top left corner"

For more details you can read this article https://programmingwithswift.com/difference-between-frame-and-bounds-in-swift/

Comment: Yup. Tried using both. But no difference.

Comment: Have you tried implementing and passing `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` delegate?

Comment: Yes... Inside the PopViewController.... updated code for reference.

Comment: I don't think the `PopViewController` that is being presented is the one that should implement it. It should be rather the one want that presents it (the one that has launchButton) IMHO.

Also you might be able to get away with only `sourceView` being defined.